# Checking whether two dates are in the same year

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm making a program for an insurance company that consists of `datePickers`. The user can select a date for starting the policy and then select a date where they made a claim. For each claim within 1 year of the start date of the policy increase the premium by 20%. However no matter what way I try this the premium still goes up by 20% even if the user has made a claim that was over a year ago. My policy starts off at 500£ if I set my start policy date as 26/07/2017 and then set my claim date to the 05/07/2016 which is over a year from the start policy date I still get back 600 as it has added on 20% to the policy. It should have stayed at £500

My code is as fallows

xaml

```
<DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="dpkStartDateOfPolicy"  Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" />
        <DatePicker Name="dpkClaim1"  Grid.Row="15" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

xaml.cs

```
 int policy = 500;
        double Chauffeur = 0.10;
        double Accountant = 0.10;
        double age2125 = 0.20;
        double age2675 = 0.10;
        double claimOneYear = 0.20;
        double tempPolicy;

        // Calculation for Claim in the last year
       public void claimOneYearMethod ()
            {

            tempPolicy = (tempPolicy + tempPolicy * claimOneYear);
            txtPolicy.Text = tempPolicy.ToString();


        }

   // Code for claim within the last year.
            DateTime Claim1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dpkClaim1.SelectedDate);

            DateTime StartPolicy = Convert.ToDateTime(dpkStartDateOfPolicy.SelectedDate);
            if ( StartPolicy.Age().Years() <1 && Claim1 )
            {
                claimOneYearMethod();
            }
```

Extention.cs

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static TimeSpan Age(this DateTime dt)
    {
        return (DateTime.Now - dt);
    }

    public static int Years(this TimeSpan ts)
    {
        return (int)((double)ts.Days / 365.2425);
    }
}
```

I have also tried this

```
 if ( StartPolicy.Age().Years() <1 && Claim1.Age().Years() == 0 )
            {
                claimOneYearMethod();
            }
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: For each claim within 1 year of the start date of the policy increase the premium by 20%. Even when the claim was over a year ago the policy was still going up by 20%. What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: You want to check if two dates are within a year of each other? Your question needs to be more specific and keep only relevant code for the actual question.

Comment: It is all relevant code it's how I'm doing my calculations.

Comment: Could you provide a sample input with the current output and what is your desired output?

Comment: @FirstStep for example if I set my start policy date as 26/07/2017 and then set my claim date to the 05/07/2016 which is over a year from the start policy date I still get back 600 as it has added on 20% to the policy

Comment: Please add it **into** your post. as **Input:**, **Current Output:** and **Desired Output:**

Comment: @CraigGallagherf my extension works, can tell so far.

Comment: Cant get the question. `StartPolicy.Age().Years()` is clear for me. But what is Claim1? You cant do `if(Claim1)`. Its a DateTime, not a bool!?

Comment: @C4u what extension

Comment: Claim1 is the datePicker for my claim. I tried it this way also `if ( StartPolicy.Age().Years() <1 && Claim1.Age().Years() == 0 )
            {
                claimOneYearMethod();
            }`

Comment: Ok lets leave this full project-related stuff. You just want to know if `Age of StartPolicy` is smaller than 1 year AND `Age of (dateTimePicker)Claim1` is 0 years?

Comment: Have you debugged your code if `SelectedValue has a value`?

Comment: On this row `if ( StartPolicy.Age().Years() <1 && Claim1 )` you are doing `and` with a `DateTime` Does that actually compile?

Comment: No it doesn't that's why I said I tried this aswel `if ( StartPolicy.Age().Years() <1 && Claim1.Age().Years() == 0 )
            {
                claimOneYearMethod();
            }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments you've posted I tried to get a simplified test for this. This is how it looks like:

```
private void dtp_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime policy = dtpPolicy.Value;
    DateTime claim = dtpClaim.Value;

    if (policy.Age().Years() < 1 && claim.Age().Years() == 0)
    {
        lblresult.Text = "Result is: true";
    }
    else
        lblresult.Text = "Result is: false";
}
```

This is the already used extension (original):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static TimeSpan Age(this DateTime dt)
    {
        return (DateTime.Now - dt);
    }

    public static int Years(this TimeSpan ts)
    {
        return (int)((double)ts.Days / 365.2425);
    }
}
```

This one is working.

[image]

**Anyway something to say:** If already using WPF, you shouldnt access the pickers by name but bind the values to properties first!
**According the comments below:**

> In your example you are putting the start policy 2 years in the past but what I want is the policy in the future and if it's more than one year since a claim then the result should be £500

For this it is just:

```
if((policy - claim).Years > 1)
{
    //return your 500;
}
```

Comment: I used this and it doesn't work `DateTime Claim1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dpkClaim1.SelectedDate);
            DateTime StartPolicy = Convert.ToDateTime(dpkStartDateOfPolicy.SelectedDate);
            if (StartPolicy.Age().Years() < 1 && Claim1.Age().Years() == 0)
            {
                claimOneYearMethod();
            }`

Comment: Then debug your tool. My small example shows up that the extension and the comparison is working to 100%. You question is bad formatted what makes is uncomfortable to read. Cant  see any mistake made.

Comment: Also: What means it `doesn't work`? Pick 2 `DateTimes` for the current day and it has to result `true`! If not, the problem is on your design.

Comment: I made my policy start on the 15/06/2017 and my claim on the 04/05/2016 this is over a year and I should get back £500 but I'm getting back £600.

Comment: In your example you are putting the start policy 2 years in the past but what I want is the policy in the future and if it's more than one year since a claim then the result should be £500

Comment: Omg. Dude. An `Age` in future will result in a **negative value**! So 2018 would result in `-1`, not `1`!

Comment: Sorry for all the questions I hope this is the last one. I'm getting an error on the if statement you gave me `operator cannot be applied to operands of type method group and int ` do you know how would I go about fixing this I have never seen this error before

Comment: Policy and claim in my example has to be `DateTime`. Use the convert method like you did before.

Comment: I done this and I'm still getting £500 back I selected 20/07/2017 for my start policy and 28/07/2016 for my Claim and I get £500 back I used this code `if ((StartPolicy - Claim1).Years() > 1)
            {
                claimOneYearMethod();
            }`

Comment: But for some reason when I don't select a date for my claim it works. And if it's over 2 years it seems to work aswel

Comment: There is so much chaos in here, Im close recommending to delete everything and start a new simplified clear readably question with all informations that are needed.

Comment: Yes I'm even confused and it was my question :P

Comment: I got it going the arrow was the wrong way around that's all. Thanks for putting up with me for so long. I used this code `if ((StartPolicy - Claim1).Years() < 1)
            {
                claimOneYearMethod();
            }`

Comment: Im always up with enough effort to help. As quid pro quo I expect the asking user to think about the essence of the problem. Maybe you should check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

```
    DateTime policyStart = policy.StartDate;
    DateTime endDate = policyStart.AddYears(1);

            foreach (var claim in Claims)
            {
               if(claim.ClaimDate >= policyStart && claim.ClaimDate <= endDate)
               {
                  //Code to modify policy rate
               }
            }
```

Comment: Where are you getting `StartDate` from

Comment: where ever you are. id imagine you have that data somewhere so just plug in your startdate there.

Same thing with claim dates.

Comment: i dont use wpf so im not 100% sure of the syntax but i guess it'd be something like


DateTime startDate = dpkStartDateOfPolicy.Value;

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to work `DateTime policyStart = Convert.ToDateTime(dpkStartDateOfPolicy.SelectedDate);
            DateTime endDate = policyStart.AddYears(1);

            
            
                if (Claim1 >= policyStart && Claim1 <= endDate)
                {
                claimOneYearMethod();
            }`